# Approach to querying most 'regular' spending customer (AdventureWorks)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am pretty new to writing queries and SQL language.

I have a problem in figuring out how to write a query to find out which customer from the AdventureWorks db has been the most consistent in spending money.

What does consistent mean? Like a customer who makes orders every year even though he/she might not spend too much on his/her orders? Any input on how to start writing this query would be very much helpful.

These are some of the fields in the table I am thinking of working with for the problem.

**SalesOrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, SalesPersonID, TotalDue**

Comment: The word "consistent" here is very much dependent on the asker.  Is this like a school assignment or something?  Ask the person who is asking you to get this data what they mean by "consistent" and then come back and edit the question to reflect what the specific requirements are.

Comment: It is for a work practice. I asked the person in charge of this "teaching" sort of this practice, he didn't have any answer. Just some food for thought like I have mentioned in my post.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Please do a research for Aggregate functions and try to apply them to your table. I guess one of the functions will help you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

definition of consistent: unchanging in nature, standard, or effect over time

If we are talking about a customer spending money, I think consistency would be gauging the amount of orders versus time...you could create a temporary table to store aggregate data...something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_customerAverageDayBetweenSale
(   
     @CustomerID INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

WITH RowOrderedOrderDatesCTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by OrderDate) as row, OrderDate
    FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
), DateChangesCTE as (
    SELECT DATEDIFF(dd, o2.OrderDate, o1.OrderDate) as DifferentBetweenDates
    FROM RowOrderedOrderDatesCTE o1 left outer join
        RowOrderedOrderDatesCTE o2 on o1.row = o2.row + 1
)
SELECT AVG(cast(DifferentBetweenDates as decimal)) As AverageDaysBetweenSales
FROM DateChangesCTE
WHERE DifferentBetweenDates is NOT NULL 

)

CREATE TABLE #CustomerConsistency (

 CustomerID INT
,AverageDayBetweenOrder Decimal
,NumberOfOrders INT

)  

INSERT INTO #CustomerConsistency

SELECT  

SOH.[CustomerID] 
,(SELECT CAST(AverageDaysBetweenSales As Decimal) FROM dbo.udf_customerAverageDayBetweenSale(SOH.CustomerID))
,Count(*) 

FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] As SOH
GROUP BY CustomerID 


SELECT * FROM #CustomerConsistency
WHERE AverageDayBetweenOrder IS NOT Null
ORDER BY NumberOfOrders, AverageDayBetweenOrder; 

DROP TABLE #CustomerConsistency
```

**EDIT:**

In reference to request to explain:

CREATE FUNCTION above is using an inline-table valued function which is well-documented here:

[Using Inline-Table Valued Functions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx)

Inside the Function [udf_customerAverageDayBetweenSale] I was using a Common Table Expression, which is well documented here:

[Using CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

One issue I noticed is the average inside the Function, generated with the AVG() function is returning a rounded number.  I tried to use the CAST() function to convert it to a decimal, but it needs some more work.  CAST is a function you can use to convert a column to different datatypes. If you could get the decimal it would allow more refined ranking.

It was a rough draft of how one could approach the problem of determining consistency of customer spending through T-SQL, exploring different SQL constructs. It is an interesting question and I would like to see other comments. I think it would be more beneficial to look also at money spent.

Comment: I am trying to understand code and run it in SSMS. But it doesn't run anything as I get an error messages like "Create Function must be the only statement in the batch", or "Incorrect syntax near the word CREATE", etc...

Comment: Never mind. I was executing it wrong. Are you able to briefly explain how you are calculating the AverageDaysBetweenOrders and AverageDaysBetweenSales? I am still trying to figure out the codes above as I haven't learned many functions like CREATE Function, CAST, etc.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It was kind of an advanced query...there is a lot going on there and I can try and explain it by editing my original post to include comments